# Where to get the "latest" ASP .NET Preview DLL and Script

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to download the ASP .NET AJAX Futures but I can only see old versions of the DLL via sample tutorials from other websites. I need the DLL to use the Drag and Drop feature according to these tutorials. I know the tutorial is already old but I was wondering if they are still supported? (Microsoft.Web.Preview.dll, PreviewDragDrop.js)

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135985.aspx#S1

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Drag-and-Drop-Programming-in-Microsoft-ASP-NET-AJAX/

http://aspalliance.com/1300_Custom_Client_Side_Drag_and_Drop_Behavior_in_ASPNET_AJAX.9
```

I was wondering why the preview and CTP is not available in the official website of ASP.NET AJAX?

```
http://download.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=AjaxControlToolkit&DownloadId=93514&FileTime=129030372855470000&Build=15987
```

I  did find a question that says to download the 2007 CTP. But it is 2 years old. Is this the latest?

```
http://forums.asp.net/t/1380745.aspx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source for information on ASP.NET and all things AJAX related is Scott Guthrie's blog. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/15/announcing-microsoft-ajax-library-preview-6-and-the-microsoft-ajax-minifier.aspx), for example, for details of the latest version.